# How to use result of scala's List::groupBy?

Tags: scala

I have this code. `PartnerReader.fetchParters()` returns a `List[Partner]`.  Partners have a `country` attribute that is a `String`, and a `dates` attribute that is a list of `Calendar` objects. I group all Partners by their country.  I expect `partnersByCountry` is a `Map[String, List[Partner]]`.

I then want to associate countries with all the dates from all their Partners. `getAllDatesForPartners()` returns a `List[Calendar]` resulting (hopefully) in a `Map[String, List[Calendar]]`.  I attempt to do this with the assignment to `allDatesForCountry`, but this fails on the call to `map` with the error `Cannot resolve overloaded method 'map'`.

Why does this code not work and what's the correct way to do the transformation?

```
val partnersByCountry = PartnerReader.fetchPartners()
      .groupBy(_.country)
val allDatesForCountry = partnersByCountry
      .map((country: String, partners: List[Partner]) => {
        country -> getAllDatesForPartners(partners)
     })

def getAllDatesForPartners(partners: List[Partner]): List[Calendar] = ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `.map()` over a `Map[?,?]` you get a sequence of tuples. To break each tuple into its constituent parts you need pattern matching.

```
.map{case (country: String, partners: List[Partner]) =>
  country -> getAllDatesForPartners(partners)
}
```

Which is the long (documented) way to write...

```
.map(tup => (tup._1, getAllDatesForPartners(tup._2)))
```